# Memory error while running LSTM Autoencoders

Tags: python-3.x, keras, sequence, lstm, autoencoder

I am setting up an LSTM Autoencoder with multivariant time sequences. Each of my sequence has different time steps(approximately 30 million steps in one sequence) and 6 features. I know to give one sequence as input to the LSTM Autoencoder, I have to reshape my sequence as (1,30million,6).I reshaped all of my 9 sequences in a similar manner. I want the autoencoder to reconstruct my sequences. However my program is crashing due to large number of time steps in each sequence. How can I solve this memory error. Even if I am giving data in batch size,my program is running out of memory. I am new to machine learning and sequence learning, so please help me with the same.My network is attached below:
`

def repeat_vector(args):

```
 [layer_to_repeat, sequence_layer] = args

 return RepeatVector(K.shape(sequence_layer)[1])(layer_to_repeat)
```

encoder_input = Input(shape=(None, self._input_features))

encoder_output = LSTM(self._latent_space)(encoder_input)

decoder_input = Lambda(repeat_vector, output_shape=(None, self._latent_space))([encoder_output, encoder_input])

decoder_output = LSTM(self._input_cells, return_sequences=True)(decoder_input)

self._autoencoder = Model(encoder_input, decoder_output)
`

I have already tried to take input via hdf files.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what system configuration are you using. OOMs can be solved from both software and hardware ends. If you are using a system with say 4GB RAM and some i5 processor(assuming it's intel), it might not work. If you are working on a GPU(which is not very likely.) it should not be a hardware issue.

If your system has a graphic card, well then you can optimize the code a bit.

> 1. Try a batch size of 1.
> 2. If you have a pre-processing queue etc. try to tweak the queue size.
> 3. I would suggest you to try this for a smaller series once before going in for the complete thing, and check if it works.
> 4. If you take the time step to be large, it will lose precision and if it's too small, well then it's heavy to compute. Check for each one
>      of them, if the time step can be increased, without compromising much
>      on precision.
> 5. You can use PCA for knowing the important features and reduce dimensionality. You can also use random forest as a preprocessing step
>      to know the feature importance and reduce the features with less
>      inportance.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer  . My program is still running OOM when I am using batch size of 1. My number of features are already small( i.e. 4). The problem with my sequence is the number of time-steps is too large(i.e. 30 million). When I am using a small sequence( with 0.1 million time-steps), then the code is working fine. I am not working with a GPU.

Comment: Please try using Google Colaboratory. It gives a free GPU instance. But don't close it before training. You can go to Runtime > Change Runtime > Hardware accelerators> "make it GPU".  You can check the colab using tricks here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402005/how-to-train-model-with-remaining-epochs-after-long-running-session-has-ended-in/54473868#54473868

Comment: Hi, I am already training the data on colabs now. Again,it is running out of memory because of number of time-steps.

Comment: Should I divide my sequence as sub-sequences and then give it to lstm autoencoder? For example if I reshape my sequence(1,30million,4) as (10,3million,4) and then give it to LSTM. But then would it loose time dependency between the sub-sequences? If yes, how can I maintain the dependency between the sequences?

Comment: Instead of increasing the time step, what I would suggest is to break your complete seq. in manageable parts. Train on the first part, then the same model on the second and so on. This is transfer learning. Make sure you feed these parts of the series in chronological order. You will have to save the weights after each training then reload them back when you feed in second part of the series

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. Doesn't LSTM autoencoder update the state of it's next timestep with the previous timestep? So why is my memory going out of bounds even if my timesteps are 30 million? I am also attaching my network configuration:

Comment: How can I add the update step in the autoencoder?  I have added the network in the question above